# InnoDB index concurrent inserts

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, mariadb, concurrency

I have an InnoDB table with an index on it. I have a few million rows to insert, so I thought I might take advantage of the row-level locking and do it in parallel. I'm inserting in batches of 10000, each in a transaction.

Because there may be clashes, I need to make a decision for each row:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (a, b, c)
values ('a', 'b', 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
a = IF(c<VALUES(c), a, VALUES(a)),
b = IF(c<VALUES(c), b, VALUES(b)),
c = IF(c<VALUES(c), c, VALUES(c));
```

If I run a few (e.g. 10) parallel insertion threads, is this a good idea? Will it cause me deadlocks due to contention on the index?

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see the `PRIMARY KEY` and the "index".

100-1000 is optimal (10K *might* be ok) for "batching" `INSERT`s -- That is, a single `INSERT` statement with 100 to 1000 rows in it.

You have shown a single row being inserted.  Will it work change to

```
values ('a', 'b', 3), ('c', 'd', 4), ...
```

That might give you a 10-fold speedup.

That is also pretty good for the size of a transaction.  You could also set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`.

Parallel threads might help.  In that case, transactions are vital, plus code to replay a transaction if it fails.  And you might be better off with 100 rows at a time -- to minimize deadlocks or delays due to other locking.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be 70% of available RAM (assuming you are using `ENGINE=InnoDB`).